# Issue on changing style in LaTeX

Tags: symbols, packages, document-classes

Currently I have a TeX document, written using *sig-alternate.cls* class file. I need to change it and use *llncs.cls*. However, when I attempt to compile the document with the class changed, I get the following error:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<recently read> \mathbb
```

If I comment the corresponding line, it gives an error on the next one:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<recently read> \rightarrowtail
```

and so on, deprecating me of several mathematical symbols' usage, which seems strange to me - aren't `\mathbb` and `\rightarrowtail` standard keywords in TeX? And how can it be that some style file prevents me from using them? I have checked this on a simple example:

```
\documentclass{llncs}
\begin{document}
$\rightarrowtail$
\end{document}
```

This leads to an error, but when I change the `documentclass` to *sig-alternate.cls*, everything works well. Also, if I write a simple document with *llncs.cls* without usage of these symbols, everything is OK too. I will be very grateful for your help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to use the `amssymb` package to use `\mathbb` and `\rightarrowtail`. It seems as if `sig-alternate.cls` loads this package, whereas `llncs.cls` does not.

From `sig-alternate.cls`:

```
[...]
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
[...]
```

Comment: @Axioplase: oops, double-clicked on accept button )))